Showing $\cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi}{12}\right)}\left( 1+\frac{1}{4}\sin^2{\left( \frac{\pi}{8} \right)}\right)^2 > 1$ without a calculator
Is there a way to show that

$$\cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi}{12}\right)}\left( 1+\frac{1}{4}\sin^2{\left( \frac{\pi}{8} \right)}\right)^2 > 1$$

is true without a calculator ?  Putting the exact value of sin and cos terms, the expression comes in the radical form $\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\left(\frac{18-\sqrt{2}}{16}\right)^2$ from  which I wasn't able to make any progress.

If you're allowed to assume that radical expression, then you can brute force to show that $(2 + \sqrt{3} ) ( 18 - \sqrt{x} ) ^2 > 1024$, like by repeated squaring.

I think we are safe in assuming this radical form as they can be derived from half angle formulas. @CalvinLin . If you can add this calculation as a solution, then I will be grateful. Maybe there is also a cleaner approach.

Here is a solution (a bit out-of-left-field perhaps...):
$\cos{\frac{\pi}{12}}=\cos{(\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{4}})=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}$
So $\sec{\frac{\pi}{12}}=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{1+\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}$
$\sin^{2}{\frac{\pi}{8}}=\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{4}$
Which means $1+\frac{1}{4}\sin^2{\frac{\pi}{4}}-\sec{\frac{\pi}{12}}=1+\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{16}-\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}$
$=\frac{1}{16}(18+15\sqrt{2}-16\sqrt{6})$
Now, all that matters is that this is positive.
So $1+\frac{1}{4}\sin^2{\frac{\pi}{4}}-\sec{\frac{\pi}{12}}>0$
And since $1+\frac{1}{4}\sin^2{\frac{\pi}{4}}+\sec{\frac{\pi}{12}}>0$
We can write $(1+\frac{1}{4}\sin^2{\frac{\pi}{4}}-\sec{\frac{\pi}{12}})(1+\frac{1}{4}\sin^2{\frac{\pi}{4}}+\sec{\frac{\pi}{12}})>0$
$(1+\frac{1}{4}\sin^{2}{\frac{\pi}{8}})^2-\sec^2{\frac{\pi}{12}}>0$
$(1+\frac{1}{4}\sin^{2}{\frac{\pi}{8}})^2>\sec^2{\frac{\pi}{12}}$
Multiplying both sides by $\cos^2{\frac{\pi}{12}}$
$\cos^2{\frac{\pi}{12}}(1+\frac{1}{4}\sin^{2}{\frac{\pi}{8}})^2>1$
As required.

Wish I didn't have school so that I could type out an answer :") Great method and simplicity. +1

I'm at school too... but I'm a teacher so it is all OK.

I think there are a few typos in the solutions. @RedFive

Thanks @Sam. There probably are. If and when I find them I will fix. If they are easy fixes, you are welcome to edit. I can't see anything immediately obvious.
